# How to use datetime field froma dataframe in linregress scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When I try to `linregress` the `Date` and `Close` field from a `dataframe` I keep getting the `error`.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats_stats_mstats_common.py", >line 75, in linregress
> xmean = np.mean(x, None)
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2942, in >mean
> out=out, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py", line 65, in >_mean
> ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
> TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and >dtype('<M8[ns]')

The code I am using.

```
import openpyxl,os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from scipy.stats import linregress

start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,11,10)
i = NSE/CHENNPETRO
df = pdr.DataReader(i, 'quandl', start, end)
# df = df.iloc[::-1]
linregress(df.index,df['Close'])
```

Where can I look next?

Answer (score 7):

Scipy can only do linear regression over numerical values; it does not know how to handle dates. The best way to proceed is probably to convert your dates to numbers (e.g. number of days, number of seconds, etc. as appropriate). Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(1000) + np.random.randn(1000)},
                    index=pd.date_range('2012', periods=1000, freq='D'))
data.head()
#  x
# 2012-01-01 -0.475795
# 2012-01-02 -0.222100
# 2012-01-03  2.494785
# 2012-01-04  3.237799
# 2012-01-05  4.412078
```

Now we can use pandas [time deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html) to find the number of days since the first index:

```
# compute days since the first date in the index
delta = (data.index - data.index[0])
days = delta.days
```

Depending on your data, it may make more sense to instead use hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

With this as input, linear regression will work:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
linregress(days, data.x)
# LinregressResult(slope=0.99979977545856191, intercept=0.085015417311694819, rvalue=0.99999344600423345, pvalue=0.0, stderr=0.00011458241597036779)
```

Comment: I would add here the possibility of using pandas.to_numeric(args), useful.

Comment: @jakevdp - I don't understand your time deltas section.  If i try "seconds = delta.seconds" the code fails.  The result of data.index - data.index[0] is returning a list of int64 values.  How is this able to be used with timestamps??